# Cannot turn on bluetooth on Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 7390 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, dell, 20.04

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 7390 (2019 version) alongside Windows (dual boot). Everything seems to work fine, including wifi, except bluetooth that I don't seem to be able to turn on.

When I go to Settings > Bluetooth and turn on the BT, the window still displays "Bluetooth turned off" [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82LjH.png).

I don't know if it is related, but I found [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnYZK.png) when going to Settings > About > Software updates > Additional drivers (it reads "This device is not working" below "Intel Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i"). So there seem to be a driver issue with the Wireless adapter, which is rather strange as my wifi is working fine!

On the support.killernetworking.com website I found [this page](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/) that states: "Newer Linux Kernels like 5.4+ might have bugs and compatibility issues, so if you see issues using them, try downgrading to 5.3". I am apparently using a 5.4.0 kernel, so I wonder if this might be the issue.

I must confess that I'm a bit lost with all this and would greatly appreciate your help to sort this out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did ypu evrer get this sorted out?  Im having similar issues.

Comment: Hi, updating my kernel solved the issue.